# RFT does not recognize webelements

Tags: java, ui-automation, rft

The *RFT* Test Object is not able to identify individual Web elements in any browser. So far tested in *IE9* and *Chrome 32.0* . I have tried cleaning out all java versions but it did not work.It works in my laptop with the same setting but not in my dektop. Anyone any ideas.

```
MY RFT version:- 8.5.1  
IE version:-9  
Java version installed in machine:-1.7.0_60-ea
```

The Object Inspector just shows screen coordinates when I am expecting something like *"Html.A"* for a link for *.class* property and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Does the browser enablement test pass?

Is the issue seen on some specific site or  any website ?

If all the sites have the issue then  I wud suspect it to be  browser enablement issue.[Browser enablement requires Java to be enabled as well].

Also in IE  tools>Addons   make sure  the Rational IEEnablerClass  is enabled.

---

Check the  Next Gen plugin  in the Java Control Panel under Advanced Tab. It should be  unchecked.
Check the browser zoom level (it should be 100%).

And cud you tell .. if you try to  insert an object in the browser using the  (Insert Test Object Wizard)    what is the   class of object that RFT is able to highlith .. I mean    is it   Html.HtmlBrowser or Html.HtmlDocument   or something else.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Prakash! Yes, the browser enablement passed and I checked and confirmed that the Rational IEEEnablerClass is enabled in my browser. This is occuring for all websites that I am opening in Internet Exploer.

Comment: I checked the browser zoom level and it is 100% and my next gen plugin is also checked. When i try to use the Insert Test Object Wizard it only picks up Html.HtmlBrowser and highlights the entire browser and nothing else.